# Vaadin, JPA, Spring - simple form for entity with composed primary key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, vaadin

I have simple database model, with ability to nest product categories, like this:
[image: database model]

And I want to create basic form in Vaadin, that has **two ComboBoxes to create** this **decomposed entity**.

I **cannot bind composed key** that si constructed with @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId **to my form fields**.

When I click on button "Add category" which should bring up an empty form, **I get this error**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:559) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BeanPropertySet.invokeWrapExceptions(BeanPropertySet.java:516) ~[flow-data-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BeanPropertySet.access$600(BeanPropertySet.java:48) ~[flow-data-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BeanPropertySet$NestedBeanPropertyDefinition.lambda$getGetter$3ec26976$1(BeanPropertySet.java:200) ~[flow-data-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder$BindingImpl.initFieldValue(Binder.java:1130) ~[flow-data-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder$BindingImpl.access$200(Binder.java:972) ~[flow-data-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.lambda$setBean$1(Binder.java:1677) ~[flow-data-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.setBean(Binder.java:1677) ~[flow-data-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at cz.cvut.fit.manufacturingservices.ui.admin.view.product.category.ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm.setProductCategoryProductCategory(ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm.java:62) ~[main/:na]
    at cz.cvut.fit.manufacturingservices.ui.admin.view.product.category.ProductCategoryProductCategoryView.editProductCategoryProductCategory(ProductCategoryProductCategoryView.java:64) ~[main/:na]
    at cz.cvut.fit.manufacturingservices.ui.admin.view.product.category.ProductCategoryProductCategoryView.addProductCategoryProductCategory(ProductCategoryProductCategoryView.java:94) ~[main/:na]
    at cz.cvut.fit.manufacturingservices.ui.admin.view.product.category.ProductCategoryProductCategoryView.lambda$getToolbar$2f54d9f7$1(ProductCategoryProductCategoryView.java:78) ~[main/:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:373) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:264) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:441) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:441) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:409) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:390) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:390) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:317) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1540) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247) ~[flow-server-2.1.8.jar:2.1.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:120) ~[vaadin-spring-12.1.4.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

My composte key implmentation:

```java
@Embeddable
public class ProductCategoryProductCategoryIdentity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_parent_id", nullable = false)
    private ProductCategory productCategoryParent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_child_id", nullable = false)
    private ProductCategory productCategoryChild;

    public ProductCategory getProductCategoryParent() {
        return productCategoryParent;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryParent(ProductCategory productCategoryParent) {
        this.productCategoryParent = productCategoryParent;
    }

    public ProductCategory getProductCategoryChild() {
        return productCategoryChild;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryChild(ProductCategory productCategoryChild) {
        this.productCategoryChild = productCategoryChild;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ProductCategoryProductCategoryIdentity)) return false;
        ProductCategoryProductCategoryIdentity that = (ProductCategoryProductCategoryIdentity) o;
        return Objects.equals(getProductCategoryParent(), that.getProductCategoryParent()) &&
                Objects.equals(getProductCategoryChild(), that.getProductCategoryChild());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getProductCategoryParent(), getProductCategoryChild());
    }
}
```

Repository implmentation:

```java
public interface ProductCategoryProductCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductCategoryProductCategory, ProductCategoryProductCategoryIdentity> {
}
```

Service implementation:

```java
@Service
public class ProductCategoryProductCategoryService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ProductCategoryProductCategory.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private ProductCategoryProductCategoryRepository productCategoryProductCategoryRepository;

    public List<ProductCategoryProductCategory> findAll() {
        return productCategoryProductCategoryRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(ProductCategoryProductCategory productCategoryProductCategory) {
        if (productCategoryProductCategory == null) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot save null product category decomposition");
            return;
        }
        productCategoryProductCategoryRepository.save(productCategoryProductCategory);
    }
}
```

Form component implementation:

```java
public class ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm extends FormLayout {
    ComboBox<ProductCategory> productCategoryParent = new ComboBox<>("Parent product category");
    ComboBox<ProductCategory> productCategoryChild = new ComboBox<>("Child product category");

    Button save = new Button("Save");
    Button close = new Button("Close");

    Binder<ProductCategoryProductCategory> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(ProductCategoryProductCategory.class);

    public ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm(List<ProductCategory> productCategories) {
        addClassName("product_category-form");

        productCategoryParent.setItems(productCategories);
        productCategoryParent.setItemLabelGenerator(ProductCategory::getLabel);
        productCategoryChild.setItems(productCategories);
        productCategoryChild.setItemLabelGenerator(ProductCategory::getLabel);

        //binder.bind(productCategoryParent, "id.productCategoryParent");
        //binder.bind(productCategoryChild, "id.productCategoryChild");

        //binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        add(productCategoryParent, productCategoryChild, createButtonsLayout());
    }


    private Component createButtonsLayout() {
        save.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        close.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);

        save.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
        close.addClickShortcut(Key.ESCAPE);

        save.addClickListener(event -> validateAndSave());
        close.addClickListener(event -> fireEvent(new CloseEvent(this)));

        binder.addStatusChangeListener(e -> save.setEnabled(binder.isValid()));

        return new HorizontalLayout(save, close);
    }

    public void setProductCategoryProductCategory(ProductCategoryProductCategory productCategoryProductCategory) {
        binder.setBean(productCategoryProductCategory);
    }

    private void validateAndSave() {
        if (binder.isValid()) {
            fireEvent(new SaveEvent(this, binder.getBean()));
        }
    }


    public static abstract class ProductCategoryProductCategoryFormEvent extends ComponentEvent<ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm> {
        private final ProductCategoryProductCategory productCategoryProductCategory;

        protected ProductCategoryProductCategoryFormEvent(ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm source, ProductCategoryProductCategory productCategoryProductCategory) {
            super(source, false);
            this.productCategoryProductCategory = productCategoryProductCategory;
        }

        public ProductCategoryProductCategory getProductCategoryProductCategory() {
            return productCategoryProductCategory;
        }
    }

    public static class SaveEvent extends ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm.ProductCategoryProductCategoryFormEvent {
        SaveEvent(ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm source, ProductCategoryProductCategory productCategoryProductCategory) {
            super(source, productCategoryProductCategory);
        }
    }

    public static class DeleteEvent extends ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm.ProductCategoryProductCategoryFormEvent {
        DeleteEvent(ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm source, ProductCategoryProductCategory productCategoryProductCategory) {
            super(source, productCategoryProductCategory);
        }

    }

    public static class CloseEvent extends ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm.ProductCategoryProductCategoryFormEvent {
        CloseEvent(ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm source) {
            super(source, null);
        }
    }

    public <T extends ComponentEvent<?>> Registration addListener(Class<T> eventType, ComponentEventListener<T> listener) {
        return getEventBus().addListener(eventType, listener);
    }
}
```

View implementation:

```java
@Route(value = "product-category-product-category", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class ProductCategoryProductCategoryView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final Grid<ProductCategoryProductCategory> grid = new Grid<>(ProductCategoryProductCategory.class);
    private final ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm form;

    @Autowired
    private ProductCategoryProductCategoryService productCategoryProductCategoryService;

    public ProductCategoryProductCategoryView(ProductCategoryService productCategoryService) {
        form = new ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm(productCategoryService.findAll());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        addClassName("product_category-view");
        setSizeFull();

        configureGrid();
        configureForm();

        add(getToolbar(), getContent());

        updateList();
        closeEditor();
    }

    private void configureForm() {
        form.addListener(ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm.SaveEvent.class, this::saveProductCategoryProductCategory);
        form.addListener(ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm.CloseEvent.class, e -> closeEditor());
    }

    private void configureGrid() {
        grid.addClassName("product_category-grid");
        grid.setSizeFull();

        //grid.setColumns("parentId", "childId");

        grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(evn -> editProductCategoryProductCategory(evn.getValue()));
    }

    private void editProductCategoryProductCategory(ProductCategoryProductCategory productCategoryProductCategory) {
        if (productCategoryProductCategory == null)
            closeEditor();
        else {
            form.setProductCategoryProductCategory(productCategoryProductCategory);
            form.setVisible(true);
            addClassName("editing");
        }
    }

    private void closeEditor() {
        form.setProductCategoryProductCategory(null);
        form.setVisible(false);
        removeClassName("editing");
    }

    private HorizontalLayout getToolbar() {
        Button addProductCategoryButton = new Button("Add category");
        addProductCategoryButton.addClickListener(click -> addProductCategoryProductCategory());

        HorizontalLayout toolbar = new HorizontalLayout(addProductCategoryButton);
        toolbar.addClassName("toolbar");
        return toolbar;
    }

    private Component getContent() {
        Div content = new Div(grid, form);
        content.setSizeFull();
        content.addClassName("content");
        return content;
    }

    private void addProductCategoryProductCategory() {
        grid.asSingleSelect().clear();
        editProductCategoryProductCategory(new ProductCategoryProductCategory());
    }

    private void updateList() {
        grid.setItems(productCategoryProductCategoryService.findAll());
    }

    private void saveProductCategoryProductCategory(ProductCategoryProductCategoryForm.SaveEvent event) {
        productCategoryProductCategoryService.save(event.getProductCategoryProductCategory());
        updateList();
        closeEditor();
    }
}
```

Could you help me solve it or provide me simple entity with composed primary (foreign) key together with simple form to create that entity?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In order to attract good answers, you should describe *why* you cannot bind the composed key to the form. What have you tried so far? How have you set up your form and its binding? Also, could you provide your related java classes instead of an uml?

Comment: @kscherrer thanks for the advice, I ve updated my question. Now it includes code snippets.

Comment: When you say "you cannot", what does that mean? Do you get errors? What does not work? Having the code surely helps, but it is a lot to sift through.

Comment: @cfrick I have updated my question and added error log. (I should have done it from the beginning, thanks for reminding me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error log says that there was a NullPointerException while trying to access a bound attribute of the `ProductCategoryProductCategory` instance during `binder::setBean`. 
I guess its the embeddable id thats null (without reading all the code), but you should either initialize the object with all needed values before binding, or check for null value of `item.getId()` in the binding.

Because you have a nested property bound, I think you need to declare the binding not via property-string, so you can add null-checks for `item.getId()` before calling `item.getId().getProductCategoryParent()` or its setter respectively.

```
binder.forField(productCategoryParent)
    .bind(                      // but if the id itself is null, don't try to get its parent
        (item) -> item.getId() == null ? null : item.getId().getProductCategoryParent(), 
        (item, value) -> {
            if(item.getId() != null){
                item.getId().setProductCategoryParent(value);
            }
        }
);
```

edit: removed mentioning of nullRepresentation as its a combobox and not a textfield. If the productCategoryParent were null, it would work, but its the `ProductCategoryProductCategoryIdentity` that is null.

Comment: Almost there. Now my forms show up, but after selecting any value `java.lang.NullPointerException` is thrown. Do I need to somehow manually instantiate ProductCategoryProductCategoryIdentity? 
I am passing `new ProductCategoryProductCategory()` from my view to my form component.

Comment: when you are passing a new `ProductCategoryProductCategory`, the embedded id is most definitely null if you dont set it within the constructor. Yes you have to instantiate it, if youre not loading it from db. However, I don't see where this new NPE is coming from, my null checks should prevent them.

Comment: but it should also work if you leave the whole embedded id null, using above code. No idea where NPE is coming from. Maybe it's because after setting value of combobox, there is now a discrepancy between input state and bound item state. You should probably disable the combobox as long as the item has no embedded id, Until the item has an embedded id

Comment: There are two scenarios. 1) enabled null check in field setter and not instantiated Identity -> resulting in org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: null id generated for . in my service layer. 2) disabled null check in field setter and not insantiated Identity class -> NPE in form class.
So I had to instantiate Identity in View and then I could remove null check in field setter. But this generated new unwanted behavior of duplicating item after edit. Because id has changed and JPA creates new entity on save. It is correct behavior, but unwanted :). I will try to change logic somehow.

Comment: yeah that is now outside the question scope. maybe dont cascade save and merge actions, and handle new/edit/delete actions of the ids separately. you could do this in the service layer

Comment: Sure, I had a same idea. Thanks for everything.